# Regex MULTILINE not working?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

In the example module below. The pattern only matches the first part of the string. How to make it match and display all the substrings matching the pattern?

```
 filtered ='\n\rweakmoves (1835) seeking 5 0 unrated blitz ("play 89" to respond)\n\r\n\rGuestKCCZ (++++) seeking 15 0 unrated standard ("play 91" to respond)\n\r\n\rGuestKKKP (++++) seeking 3 0 unrated blitz f ("play 59" to respond)\n\r'

rgxseeking =re.compile(r'^\S+\s\(([\d+-]+)\)\s+seeking\s+(\d+\s\d+)\s+(\S{1,7})\s(\S{1,9})(\s\[\S+\])?((\s[fm])?)((\s[fm])?)\s\("play\s\d{1,3}\"\sto\srespond\)$',re.MULTILINE)

    seeking= re.search(rgxseeking,filtered)
    if seeking:
       print seeking.group()
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Here is the incoming input from the server

```
  FICS.username=username ="guest"
  FICS.password=password =""
  self.logged = logged = False
  self.username = username = False
  self.closed = closed = False
  self.parsetime = parsetime = 5000
  self.timeout = timeout = 5000

  try:
        self.host = "69.36.243.188"
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((self.host, timeout))
        self.sock.settimeout(2)
        self.sock.setblocking(0)

   except Exception as inst:
         print type(inst)     # the exception instance
         print inst.args      # arguments stored in .args
         print inst           # __str__ allows args to printed directly
```

The data coming in collected from this regex

```
#for Analysis of string format
rgxunwanted = '.*'
unwanted = re.findall(rgxunwanted, raw, re.DOTALL)
    if unwanted:
    print unwanted
```

A chunk of the data returned by the module above:

```
 ["earn how to ask for help on the help channel.\n\r  type 'help register' to learn how to get a registered account.\n\r  type 'help interfaces' for information on getting a graphical interface.\n\r  type 'showadmins' to see which admins (FICS administrators) are logged on.\n\r  type 'set shout 1' to see shouts (only registered users may shout).\n\r  type 'set seek 0' if receiving ads for matches bothers you.\n\r  type 'set open 0' if you do not want to be challenged to a chess match.\n\r  type 'set silence 1' if you wish to have quiet play.\n\r  type 'getgame' to get a blitz chess game.\n\r\n\rSpecial channels for guests:\n\r  type 'tell 4 <message>' if you need help\n\r  type 'tell 53 <message>' to chat with other users\n\r\n\r  A quick guide is available on our web page: http://www.freechess.org\n\r   as are facilities to register, connect via a java interface or download\n\r   interfaces, so that you get a graphical board and can use the mouse.\n\r\n\rNOTE:  Guests with foul or abusive names may be 'nuked' without warning!!!\n\r\n\rfics% \n\rGuestWW", '']
['DS (++++) seeking 10 0 unrated blitz [white] ("play 26" to respond)\n\rfics% \n\rROBOadmin(*)(TD) tells you: Welcome to FICS - the Free Internet Chess Server. \n\r\\   Please visit our homepage at http://www.freechess.org. From there you can \n\r\\   register or download a graphical interface. You can get help by asking a \n\r\\   question in channel 4 - use "tell 4 My question is...". Or you can get \n\r\\   help from one of our service representives; these are marked (SR) and can \n\r\\   be seen with "showsrs"\n\rfics% \n\rGuestRCBT (++++) seeking 15 0 unrated standard ("play 121" to respond)\n\rfics% \n\rGuestHPZR (++++) seeking 5 5 unrated blitz ("play 2" to respond)\n\rfics% \n\rGuestBGVC (++++) seeking 5 0 unrated blitz ("play 95" to respond)\n\rfics% \n\rGuestRGYQ (++++) seeking 3 0 unrated blitz ("play 83" to respond)\n\rfics% \n\rGuestCSXP (++++) seeking 3 2 unrated blitz ("play 103" to respond)\n\rfics% ', '']
['\n\rGuestXQHW (++++) seeking 10 0 unrated blitz f ("play 11" to respond)\n\rfics% ', '']
['\n\rGuestPDXX (++++) seeking 10 0 unrated blitz f ("play 35" to respond)\n\rfics% ', '']
['\n\rGuestBGYP (++++) seeking 2 12 unrated blitz m ("play 22" to respond)\n\rfics% \n\rGuestZKGP (++++) seeking 5 0 unrated blitz ("play 52" to respond)\n\rfics% \n\rGuestMFLK (++++) seeking 10 0 unrated blitz ("play 56" to respond)\n\rfics% \n\rGuestZSTH (++++) seeking 13 5 unrated standard ("play 59" to respond)\n\rfics% ', '']
['\n\rGuestSHQS (++++) seeking 3 0 unrated blitz f ("play 65" to respond)\n\rfics% \n\rGuestXPSS (++++) seeking 6 5 unrated blitz f ("play 62" to respond)\n\rfics% ', '']
```

Finally when i run this regex it only returns the first "seeking" substring instead of all of them in the messages. raw is the unformated message from the server i have pasted above. Please note i have added \s. I have also tried \s* and [\n\r] with [\n] at the end and enclosing the regex with ^$ and running in multiline:

```
# \n\r  \n
#Working - ongoing
#GuestFCKN (++++) seeking 5 0 unrated blitz [white] f ("play 11" to respond)
#GuestQWHB (++++) seeking 15 5 unrated standard [white] ("play 122" to respond)
#GuestQWHB (++++) seeking 15 5 unrated standard f m ("play 122" to respond)
#GuestQWHB (++++) seeking 15 5 unrated standard f ("play 122" to respond)
#GuestQWHB (++++) seeking 15 5 unrated standard ("play 122" to respond)

 rgxseeking =re.compile(r'\s\S+\s\(([\d+-]+)\)\s+seeking\s+(\d+\s\d+)\s+(\S{1,7})\s(\S{1,9})(\s\[\S+\])?((\s[fm])?)((\s[fm])?)\s\("play\s\d{1,3}\"\sto\srespond\)',re.MULTILINE)
 seeking= re.search(rgxseeking,filtered)
 if seeking:
     print seeking.group()
```

Comment: What should a match consists of?

Comment: The DOS/Windows/network style of line separator is `\r\n`, so why are you using `\n\r`?  If that's how the text is being generated, then that's what you have to fix.

Comment: @hwnd: a match should return the sub strings without \n\r\ and \n. Once it works i will break it down to extract values like time etc.. The data contained in the substring follow the format  (Name of the player searching for an opponent) ((rating)) seeking (time time increment) (rated|unrated) (blitz|standard|suicide|etc.) ([colour]) (f|m) \("play(board number)" to respond)

Comment: @Alan Moore. I don't decide on the format. It is fed from a Telnet server i connect to on (host=freechess.org,sock=5000). I will add more info to clarify running a .* on the incoming messages. Sorry it wasn't clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seeking` returns `None`, so add lookahead assertion `(?=\s*)` at the begining of regex. Fixed regex is below

```
rgxseeking =re.compile(r'^(?=\s*)\S+\s\(([\d+-]+)\)\s+seeking\s+(\d+\s\d+)\s+(\S{1,7})\s(\S{1,9})(\s\[\S+\])?((\s[fm])?)((\s[fm])?)\s\("play\s\d{1,3}\"\sto\srespond\)$',re.MULTILINE)
```

Raw data returned from server can be splited with string `'\n\r'`. Then you will have following code

```
if raw:
    for line in raw.split('\n\r'):
        seeking = re.search(rgxseeking, line)
        if seeking:
            print seeking.group()
```

Comment: This fixes the problem, because a "line" is defined by `\n`. The extra `\r` after `\n` is considered to be after the start of the line.

Comment: Yes it does. However.. i have updated my question with more precise data for which it doesn't. :) . sorry

Comment: @user2718378: updated regex and added example for your input data

Comment: Yep. Does it. Thanks very much. Also helps me in my next step where i will parse all server messages in lines. Weird can't be done without splitting first. Any more elegant way possible you think?